# Accessing URL variables in Aweber generated URL string

Tags: url, aweber

I use the Aweber API to add members to a list - and the settings are configured to pass variables back to my page for processing.

That all works fine - but the issue I'm having is with the url - the url is appended as follows:

```
http://someurl.com/processing.cfm&thisvar=this&custom Organisation=Some Name
```

On the face of it that should be fine - but my processing is returning an error of

```
Element CUSTOM is undefined in URL
```

I'm wondering if it is because of the space between custom and organisation?

I have also tried to access the URL object Organisation - but get the same Element Organisation is undefined in URL message.

Any advice appreciated?

Thanks as always!

Simon

Answer (score 0):

The space is certainly the reason, it must have an equals sign in it. What library is appending this?

Comment: The URL is appended by the aweber API - I'm in touch with them, and will update the response in case it helps others.

Comment: It would be a bug in their system then. To continue on in the meantime just create a small piece of code to replace '&custom ' with '&custom= '. This will at least get you going forward and also ensure that this is the reason.